# What is the latest akka version that can be used with 1.3.4 spray?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

[Here](http://spray.io/project-info/current-versions/#id4)  it is written:

> spray 1.3.4 is built against Scala 2.10.5 and Akka 2.3.9 as well as
>   Scala 2.11.6 and Akka 2.3.9.

Does this mean that

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.12"
"io.spray" %% "spray-can" % "1.3.4"
```

in `build.sbt` is a bad combination ?

Is the latest version of akka compatible with spray "2.3.9" ?

Comment: Related : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Conflict+Management

Comment: I would assume it's not compatible, as akka-actor 2.4.12 is not compatible with 2.3.9. Recommended way forward is to port to akka-http (see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/migration-guide/migration-from-spray.html)

Comment: I know it isn't recommended to use spray and akka 2.4 together but I tried it in a relatively large Spray app that I have and all the tests still passed. I agree with Stefano's comment above that all in all, the best solution is to upgrade to akka-http. I've made this transition with some small Spray apps and it is relatively straightforward.

Comment: 2.3.x and 2.4.x should have binary compatibility.  It's likely possible to use the combination you show.  You will have problems with some of the testkit code.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/common/binary-compatibility-rules.html